# Subsheaves of a direct sum of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

All our sheaves are defined on the projective line.
Consider a direct sum sheaf $S=\bigoplus O_{i\in I}(a_i)$ for a finite set $I$.
If $S$ is a subsheaf of some $T=\bigoplus_{j\in J} O(1)$ for some finite set $J$, does it follow that $a_i\leqslant 1$? I have been trying to prove this by considering the long exact sequence of cohomology groups, but so far without success. I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Using the exact sequence seems a bit overkilled. Since $$Hom(O(a), O(b)) = Hom(O, O(b-a)) = H^0(O(b-a))$$ $O(a)$ can't be a subsheaf of $O(b)$ if $a > b$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I agree. At the same time remember that left exactness of global sections (which is all we are using) isn't hard to prove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go with your approach. If $\mathcal \oplus_{i \in I} \mathcal O(a_i)$ is a subsheaf of $\oplus_{j \in J}\mathcal O(1)$, then so is $\mathcal O(a_i)$, for each $i\in I$. So for each $i\in I$, we have a short exact sequence,
$$ 0 \to  \mathcal O(a_i)\to \oplus_{j \in J}\mathcal O(1)\to \mathcal F \to 0.$$
Tensoring everything with $\mathcal O(-a_i)$ (which is locally free, so tensoring preserves exactness), we get
$$ 0 \to \mathcal O\to \oplus_{j \in J}\mathcal O(1-a_i)\to \mathcal F(-a_i) \to 0.$$
Now let's look at the LES:
$$ 0 \to H^0(\mathcal O) \to \oplus_{j \in J} H^0 (\mathcal O(1 - a_i)) \to H^0( \mathcal F(-a_i)) \to \dots$$
Clearly, $\mathcal H^0(\mathcal O) = k$, where $k$ is the base field.

But if $a_i > 1$, then $H^0(\mathcal O(1-a_i)) = 0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: as expected, I was being silly.. I knew it should work like this. After midnight my brain seems to think that $H^0(O)$ is $0$-dimensional.. thanks!